# How to transfer a list of strings from a file to property of application.properties (using Spring boot 2.3.x)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a application.yaml

```yaml
app:
  list: /list.txt
```

- list.txt

Also I have a file with list of strings. It locates into /resources(in  the root /resource).

```
first
second
third
```

- class

```java
public class Bean{

@Value("${app.list}")
private List<String> listProp = new ArrayList<>();

public void print(){
 System.out.println(listProp);
}

}
```

I have found that:

```java
public class ResourceReader {

    public static String asString(Resource resource) {
        try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), UTF_8)) {
            return FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String readFileToString(String path) {
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(path);
        return asString(resource);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationResource {
    
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationResource {

    @Value("${app.list}")
    private String pathToFile;

    @Bean
    public List<String> resourceString() {

        String blackList = ResourceReader.readFileToString(pathToFile);
        return List.of(blackList.split("\n"));

    }
}
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HelloController {

 
    private final List<String> resourceString;
...
}
```

This is necessary in order not to manually write a list of strings to the property app.name (there are several hundred lines).

However, I find it difficult to figure out how to do it at low cost. So that it can be easily maintained.

maybe there is an easier way ? I would not like to add a hardcoding value in the configuration class

Maybe someone has some ideas ?

Comment: Does it works if we get only file name from property and read its content via ClassLoader interface? Is it low cost solution for your perspective?

Comment: Excuse me. but I don 't understand what mechanism do you mean ? You can give your own example.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-arrays-lists).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution from my understanding if you have to keep lines in the text file that you've shared:

```
public class Bean {

    @Value("${app.list}")
    private String listProp; // only get name of file

    public void print(){
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(listProp);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            for (int ch; (ch = is.read()) != -1; ) {
                sb.append((char) ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's really shorter. However, please tell me, when the application is deployed in a cluster (In its own pod), will Classloader correctly read the relative path to the file?

Comment: List<String> split = List.of(sb.toString().split("\n"));

Comment: Spring has a resource abstraction for this, use that instead.